# windowsFocusChanged() from Unity gives me sometimes NullPointerException

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to import an Unity project into an Android Studio project. I already know how to do so by managing activities but now I'm trying to do it with fragments in order to display my Unity scene only on a part of the screen while displaying some native UI on the other part.
To do so I followed this: [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/829774/importing-a-unity3d-scene-into-android-fragment.html?childToView=1345650#comment-1345650) and I modified it to adapt to my code.

```
public class UnityManagerFragment extends MyFragmentManager {

    protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;
    public FrameLayout unityFrameLayout;

    public UnityManagerFragment()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(getActivity());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unity_manager_view, container, false);

        this.unityFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.unity_fragment);
        this.unityFrameLayout.addView(mUnityPlayer.getView(), FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
        mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(true);
        return view;
    }
}
```

`MyFragmentManager` extends `Fragments` and doesn't make anything that would cause a problem, in fact, the issue appeared before I created this class.
My problem lies at the line `mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(true);` which sometimes crashes my application when I click on a button to launch my Unity fragment. The log tell me this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testfragments/com.example.testfragments.UnityFragmentContainerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.sendMessage(android.os.Message)' on a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3124)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873).
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.sendMessage(android.os.Message)' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Message.sendToTarget(Message.java:416)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.testfragments.UnityManagerFragment.onCreateView(UnityManagerFragment.java:43).
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1250)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6588)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

The method `windowsFocusChanged` comes from unity-classes.jar which is generated by Unity when I export its project and I can't modify it. I have to use it otherwise I'd get a black screen instead of seeing my scene.
I have no clue what's happening, can someone help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you found the solution?

Comment: I am also facing same issue please help me

Comment: No actually after spending a fair amount of time I gave up because I needed to work on the integration of Unity into a iOS app. Maybe later if I have the time...

Comment: Did you resolved this issue?

Comment: Now i am facing below issue if you know the solution please help me

Comment: https://stackdelivery.com/question/android-app-crash-when-i-open-unity-animation-second-time

Comment: Sorry I didn't express myself correctly. I meant I didn't find any clue or solutions so I couldn't resolve it. So I gave up because I have others things to work on and maybe once I'll do everything I have to I'll try again.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Put a null pointer check on `getActivity()` sometime fragment manager returns null reference of activity by using method getActivity();.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
I added a new NullPointerException to see whether getActivity() returns null or not and I checked the value of it. It always returns the current activity, even when my app crashes. So I don't think that's the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use Unity 2019. The issue has been Solved i am using 2019.1.10f